# How to Filter premium videos from search results

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using youtube api and some videos, which I am fetching are for YouTube premium. How can I filter them from not fetching these videos?

Comment: Please [edit] and add the code you're using. - The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Its not possible log a [feature requst](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803)

Answer (score 1):

As always YouTube Data API v3 [doesn't provide a basic feature](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource): is a given video a premium one?

I would recommend you to use my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/83c52b165f2eda46b9e1a77d61f69528b199358c/videos.php#L161-L166) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by requesting https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=isPremium&id=VIDEO_ID you'll receive a JSON where `item['isPremium']` is a boolean stating whether or not the given video is a premium one.

With that you will be able to filter premium videos in search results with an additional call to my API.

Comment: Interesting. Can you share the video_id for testing? - I have not found premium video.

Comment: Sure, here is a premium video id: [dNJMI92NZJ0](https://youtu.be/dNJMI92NZJ0)

Comment: @BenjaminLoison  I would also like to know if you have checked that what you are doing is not against googles [TOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service).  [Developer Program Policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11498144?hl=en)  It looks like it might be.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison, the page also has this value: `<meta itemprop="paid" content="True">` as alternative.

Comment: @DalmTo TLDR: Is fixing the YouTube API, that most of the time doesn't work as documented, a violation of the rules ? Honestly I quickly read the YT rules and I suspect that the solution I am proposing violates them. However, insofar as I give the world a way forward and provide tools that Google is unable to provide to scientists (within a reasonable time frame if they do so), I find that given the limited use of my very basic tools it remains reasonable. In any case if it really bothers YouTube they can very easily prevent this reasonable use by using captchas, banning IPs or contacting me.