# Youtube api to check if a video is only available to Premium users?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Has anyone had success with this either through a direct endpoint, or maybe a creative work around using the youtube api? Just trying to check if a video is only available to Premium users.

It doesn't look like `contentDetails` and `status` properties work for this.

Comment: [I already solved this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71917582).